# Protractor e2e testing with Keycloak server as token provider in Angular

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-runner, keycloak

I am new to protractor. Unable to test my component as I am unable to login to keycloak server from my startup test file `e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts` file.

I am using [keycloak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) server for authentication

In my `app.e2e-spec.ts`

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
var protractor = require('protractor');
require('../node_modules/protractor/jasminewd');
//var config = require('../settings.js').getConfig();
require('../src/assets/keycloak.json')
const config = {
  url:'http://localhost:5000/',
  user:'test',
  password:'test'
}
describe('login', function() {
  it('should login', function() {
    console.log(config);
    var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    var driver = ptor.driver;

    var findByName = function(name) {
      return driver.findElement(protractor.By.name(name));
    };

    driver.get(config.url);
    findByName('username').sendKeys(config.user);
    findByName('password').sendKeys(config.password);
    findByName('login').click();

  });
});
```

In my `keycloak.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class KeycloakService {
  private instance: Keycloak.KeycloakInstance;
  private userProfile: Keycloak.KeycloakProfile;
  private bearerExcludedUrls: string[];
  private bearerPrefix: string;
  static auth: any = {};

  constructor(private settings:AppSettings){

  }
  init(): Promise<any> {
    let keycloakAuth = Keycloak('keycloak.json');//referring setting in json file
    this.instance = keycloakAuth;  
    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
          .success(() => {
            KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
            resolve();
          })
          .error((e) => {
            reject();
          });
      });
    }

}
```

In my `component.ts` I need to login first to let my route open so I implemented
`APP_INITIALIZER` to get instance of component as below:

```
    describe('AppDashboardComponent', () => {
    let component: AppDashboardComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppDashboardComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AppDashboardComponent,
              ],
              imports: [
                  SharedModule,
                  ReactiveFormsModule,
                  HttpClientModule,
                  NGMaterialImportsModule,
                  CommonModule,
                  GrowlModule,
                  portfolioRouting
              ],
              providers: [KeycloakService,
                {
                  provide: _INITIALIZER,
                  useFactory: (config: KeycloakService) => 
                  () => config.init(),//This calls keycloak Init to goto login page
                  deps: [KeycloakService],
                  multi: true
                },
                ConfigService               
              ]
        })
    }))

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppDashboardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('img'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
        // fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

When I run `ng test` I get error "http://localhost:9876/keycloak.json 404 (Not Found)" as shown in below image.
How can I get around this issue so that I can login into external keycloak login page.

[image: Karma error]